# create javascript date UTC

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, utc

Let's say I type the following code in the console:

```
var TheDate = new Date(2012, 10, 5);
TheDate.toUTCString();
"Sun, 04 Nov 2012 23:00:00 GMT" (I'm +1 hour ahead of GMT)
```

The result is that the date is actually set to the local time. How do I create a Date that's set to UTC? If I do `TheDate.toUTCString()` I want it to say 05 Nov 2012 00:00:00 GMT.

Thanks.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use the [`Date.UTC()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) method:

```
var TheDate = new Date( Date.UTC(2012, 10, 5) );
console.log( TheDate.toUTCString() );
```

returns

```
Mon, 05 Nov 2012 00:00:00 GMT
```

> **Date.UTC**
>
> Accepts the same parameters as the longest form of the constructor, and returns the number of milliseconds in a Date object since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00, universal time.

Comment: What is the functional difference between `new Date( Date.UTC(2012, 10, 5) );` and `Date.UTC(2012, 10, 5);` ?

Comment: @JakeT. `Date.UTC()` just returns the timestamp (a number). `new Date( Date.UTC() )` will return a `Date` object.

Comment: I run  `TheDate.getTimezoneOffset();`. I don't get `0` as I would expect, any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: @JoshBowling—a Date object doesn't have an offset, they're UTC. *getTimezoneOffset* returns the offset for the host system for the moment in time represented by the Date. Change system settings to a timezone with a different offset and *getTimezoneOffset* will return a different value.

Answer (score 2):

I found a **shorthand** for it, You could also create your date in **ISO format** as `new Date('YYYY-MM-DD')` to create date as **UTC**:

```js
var DateA = new Date( '2012-11-05' );
console.log( DateA.toUTCString() );

// note the difference between input methods

var DateB = new Date( Date.UTC(2012, 10, 5) );
console.log( DateB.toUTCString() );
```

Answer (score -4):

I would suggest you use momentjs (

> momentjs.com

), then all you have to do is:

```
var theDate = new Date(2012, 10, 5),
    utcDate = moment.utc(theDate);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The author wants a Date object, moment.utc does not return a Date.