# get UTC timestamp from formated date - javascript

Tags: javascript, timestamp, utc

I have a UTC date string -> **10/30/2014 10:37:54 AM**

How do I get the timestamp for this UTC date? As far as I know, following is handling this as my local time

```
var d = new Date("10/30/2014 10:37:54 AM");
return d.getTime();
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you use a library like momentjs? http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/

Comment: Doesn't getTime() returns timestamp in UTC only? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decrease the "TimezoneOffset"

```
var d = new Date("10/30/2014 10:37:54 AM");
return d.getTime() - (d.getTimezoneOffset() *1000 * 60);
```

Also u can use the UTC function

```
var d = new Date("10/30/2014 10:37:54 AM");
return Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth()+1,d.getDate(),d.getHours(),d.getMinutes(),d.getSeconds());
```

Comment: why did you add a +1 behind d.getMonth()?

Comment: The month value is 0 based. Meaning  that "0" is January, "1" is February. But the Date.UTC function expecting 1 based value meaning that "1" is January... and so on, that why we add the +1.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Date.UTC` to create a UTC format date object.

Reference:

- [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364036/create-javascript-date-utc)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC)

```js
(function() {
  var d = new Date();
  var d1 = new Date(Date.UTC(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate(), d.getHours(), d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds()));

  console.log(+d);
  console.log(+d1);
})()
```

Answer (score 1):

If the format is fixed, you could easly parse it and use the [Date.UTC()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) API.

Answer (score 0):

A quick hack would be to append `UTC` to the end of your string before parsing:

```
var d = new Date("10/30/2014 10:37:54 AM UTC");
```

But I would advise you to use a library like moment.js, it makes parsing dates much easier

Answer (score 0):

Try `Date.parse`

```
var d = new Date("10/30/2014 10:37:54 AM");
var timstamp = Date.parse(d) / 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
Date date= new Date();
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
  SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    date = sdf.parse(date.toString());
    String timestamp = sdf2.format(date);
```