# Node js creates wrong Date object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to create correct Date object

```
new Date("December 15, 2015")
```

I expect this

```
2015-12-15T00:00:00.000Z
```

But the actual outcome is this

```
2015-12-14T16:00:00.000Z
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Seems like timezone offset.

Comment: @vlaz I read about offsets. But I dont understand - why? Because I dont create Date based on current time right? So why it gives me date object with offset?

Comment: @ArslArsl Actually, I think this is probably going to come down to a text interpretation with current locale.  It is assuming you want midnight, December 15, 2015, in your time zone.  I don't know where in the spec that is, but that's what the issue will be.

Comment: I am not sure, I am just saying what I'm seeing. You wanted 00:00 on the 15th and you got 8 hours earlier than that. I'd guess you're in a -8 timezone, and the date is automatically formatted to that.

Comment: so tricky.. what can I do to avoid this kind confusing stuff? what modules are good for that?

Comment: Doesn't look like a RFC2822 compliant date ?

Comment: `2015-12-14T16:00:00.000Z` is UTC, `2015-12-15` is your local time. Do you really want a UTC time or local time?

Comment: @ArslArsl> Check out moment.js

Comment: @adeneo I think yes, you are right. But I want to treat correctly all "human readable" strings as parameter to my Date object. What is the best choise?

Comment: @JJJ I need utc. not local time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create javascript date UTC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364036/create-javascript-date-utc)

Answer (score 3):

Run your node like this:

```
$ TZ=UTC node
```

and you don't have local time zone issues.

Comment: that's great. Is it possible to make it from the code?

Comment: Seems not or only maybe/sometimes. See here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/3286