# how get new Date() in gmt 0 when creating in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

How I can create new Date() in utc timezone 0 in node.js?

```
console.log(new Date('02-28-2017')) //2017-02-27T22:00:00.000Z
console.log(new Date('02-28-2017').toUTCString()); //Mon, 27 Feb 2017 22:00:00 GMT
console.log(new Date(new Date('02-28-2017').toUTCString())); //Mon, 27 Feb
```

i want to get:

```
console.log(new Date('02-28-2017')) //2017-02-28T00:00:00.000Z
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use timezone offset in Nodejs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615828/how-to-use-timezone-offset-in-nodejs)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [create javascript date UTC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13364036/create-javascript-date-utc)

Comment: let dt = new Date(Date.UTC(2017, 1, 28));
Possible duplicate of create javascript date UTC – JJJ  - it works, thx

Answer (score 0):

You could simple append the string "GMT" to the end of your date to get a GMT date:

```js
new Date('02-28-2017 GMT')
// "Tue, 28 Feb 2017 00:00:00 GMT"
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Why the downvote? UTC timezone 0 is in fact GMT. Appending GMT to a non-timezone date in JS will give you a date in the GMT timezone.

Answer (score -3):

```
let dt = new Date('02-28-2017');
dt.setUTCHours(0);
dt.setUTCMinutes(0);
dt.setUTCSeconds(0);
dt.setUTCMilliseconds(0);
console.log(dt.toISOString());
```

Comment: I don't know, who minus your answer, but it's not work.
 console.log(dt); //2017-02-27T00:00:00.000Z 

but i need 2017-02-28